# python : when a number is reversed with zero as ending. Does not display zero in output

Tags: python

when a number is reversed with zero as ending. Zero is not printed in the output. ex: 11120 but output=2111. Please find the attached image
code:
     [code i have written for reverse of the number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Sk87.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Sk87.jpg)

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
original_int = 21110
forward_str = str(original_int)
reverse_str = ''
for char in forward_str:
    reverse_str = char + reverse_str
print(reverse_str)
```

Result is 01112 (a string)

Comment: can you please explain this in detail. Thank you

Comment: Leading zeroes are lost in any language when numbers are expressed in their respective formats (int, float, etc.). So to retain a leading zero, you have to convert it to string, which leaves *characters* in their placed positions. I leveraged that fact to (1) change integer to string, (2) iterate through each character in the string, placing each character at the front of the string, which effectively reverses the order, and (3) leave it as a string to retain the leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

Most integer types in virtually every programming language do not show leading zeroes. If you want to reverse it with zeroes, convert to a string first. If you want leading zeroes you need to specify how many places you want to show.

Internally `11120` is stored as `00000000000000000010101101110000`, it's just shown as `11120` for readability.